# Most efficient way to change class of the anchor element based on query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Criteria - I prefer not to use any additional library, want to perform this with just pure javascript, but happy to use one if needed.

I want to add an additional class to anchor elements which have a query string of 'xyz=negate'. My page typically has more than 200 anchor elements. I am looking for the most efficient way to achieve this.

The user base for my website still has a decent number of IE 8 (intranet site) and hence looking for the most efficient code. My page has anchor elements which look like the following

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com?id=43&xyz=negate">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com?id=47&xyz=nonnegate">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com?id=3&xy=negate">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com?id=42&xyz=negate&yz=external">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com?id=43&xyz=negate">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

I want to add class to the first, fourth and fifth anchor element in the above example.

Comment: can you share a sample anchor elements which has query string of xyz=negate

Comment: In this case you need to first find all the link and the query parameter . Better add an attribute with query parameter and then use `document.queryselector`

Comment: i dont have control over the anchor elements

Comment: Select all the elements and loop with indexOf, probably the only solution that is going to work well since you are supporting an ancient browser. Unless `querySelector('[href~="&xyz"]')` is supported. Not sure what part of CSS IE8 supports anymore

Comment: Why you used `jquery` tag if you don't want to use any library?

Comment: @Mohammad - I have said that I prefer not to use but I am happy to use if it is needed.

Comment: You should post the code that you wrote to do this that works inefficiently, then we might improve it. As it stands now you're basically just asking for someone to give you code.

Comment: You have conflicting statements. You say "to anchor elements that have a query string of..." And then say "to the first anchor element...". Can you clarify which one, please?

Comment: @GeoffJames - i have provided the examples of possible anchor elements in the page and I have stated that I would like the class to be added to the first in the example provided and there will be many of them in the page.

Comment: OK, so you only need the first, right? Could you make this a little clearer in your question, please? Your question has conflicting statements, at the moment

Comment: no Geoff, i dont want just the first one. In the example that i have given i want the first one to be affected.

Comment: Right, I see your edit that's much clearer, now. Thanks. In my answer it selects all the right elements. Please let me know how you get on

Comment: can you guys atleast upvote my question? some genius just likes to downvote i think

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` in selector to match, example:

```
var links=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='xyz=negate']");
```

It will find all links with href containing **xyz=negate** in any part of attribute.

In pure js it is not possible to set class to collection like in Jquery, so we must go through every element and set class.

```
for ( var i in links ){

    links[i].classList.add("someClass");
}
```

For IE8 ( classList not exists ):

```
for ( var i in links ){

    links[i].className+="someClass";
}
```

Comment: Good idea with the `"[href*='xyz=negate']"` selector :) Not sure why the downvote, though :\

Comment: I do not now also, some guys like to downvote everythhing.

Comment: I've had it on mine, too; including the OP. Someone clearly trying to get badges by going nuts and downvoting everything... Just a quick note, however I don't think the `for` function in your edit is IE8+ compatible? Only off the top of my head...

Comment: classList is not IE8 and it is just supposed to be the first one.

Comment: You can always do a check @epascarello for it and use it/not if so/not - I've included that check in my answer for compatibility :)

Comment: I added IE8 compatble className version

Comment: I think my answer is complete for this question. Downvoting is not fair.

Comment: @epascarello, you say "it is just supposed to be the first one", but I can't see in OP where it states this? From what I can tell the OP is after all of them?

Comment: @epascarello and this "I want to add an additional class to anchor elements which have a query string of 'xyz=negate'."?

Comment: @MaciejSikora - thank you, I will try this. Yes i am not sure why the downvote, someone clearly wants to just downvote everything. Why has my question got a downvote?

Comment: @SenthilNatarajan someone is bored I think.

Comment: @MaciejSikora do you think querySelectorAll has better performance over getElementbyTagName and then filter it?

Comment: @snit80 because using getElementsByTagName give as all "a" in page, so if we have a lot of them and only few of them has wanted hrefs then we need to do loop on all "a" instead of only "a" which we need. It is very not effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in either pure vanilla JS, or also using jQuery, if you like.

The logic and principle is still the same:

- find all `a` anchor elements
  where the `href` attribute contains your preferred query string (`"xyz=negate"`) in the `href`
- loop through the matching elements and add the class (in the examples, `.someclass`) to that element

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ana4upbh/4/
*I have included both the jQuery and Vanilla JS solutions for comparison; just comment/uncomment to use either*

---

Here is a pure JS solution (IE8+ compatible):

```
// select all "a" (anchor) elements with the query string 
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='xyz=negate']");

// loop through each of the matching elements 
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var el = anchors[i];
  // add the 'someclass' class to the element (or whatever meaningful name you use)
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add('someclass');
  else
    el.someclass += ' someclass';
}
```

---

or, here is a jQuery version:

```
$("a[href*='xyz=negate']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('someclass');
});
```

or simply

```
$("a[href*='xyz=negate']").addClass('someclass');
```

---

**EDIT:**
Updated the selector to get desired elements, rather than doing the check within the loop, for performance; as suggested in comments. <strike>*I'll update the JSFiddle when I get back on the PC*</strike> *JSFiddle is now up to date*

**EDIT 2:**
Removed encapsulation of `forEach` loop into direct `for` loop, for clarity.
Added alternative jQuery solution and updated JSFiddle.

Hope this helps!

Any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Any elaboration on the downvotes, guys? I like to learn - would be good to know how I can improve my answer..? Or are people on here just trying to win a war on who's got the most votes or something? I thought this was meant to be a community, not an "every man for himself", no..?

Comment: i think selecting all links in page is very not effective way to resove this problem. My solution with * give us wanted collection and final loop is done only on wanted links not on all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I agree with you, that selector will be more efficient. Is it OK if I go ahead and edit my answer to use your idea?

Comment: @GeoffJames - your solution works, but is there a reason that you are not directly looping through the anchor array instead of passing it to another function to achieve the same? I am after something that is most efficient. I will upvote for your effort

Comment: Hi @snit80 - thanks for your suggestion. I got a bit carried away with my original JS solution. In short, I'd done the jQuery version first (as it is the shortest), and then used http://youmightnotneedjquery.com (very useful) to translate to IE8+ compatibility and didn't really give it much thought (hence abstracting the `forEach` loop, which isn't entirely necessary). I've updated my answer to now show the most efficient versions of my solutions. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to actually add the class so can you do it with just CSS?

```
a[href*="xyz=negate"]:first-child { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you do need the class it should just be

```
var elem = document.querySelector('a[href*="xyz=negate"]');
if(elem) {
    elem.className = elem.className + " active";
}
```

If it is all, it is just

```
a[href*="xyz=negate"] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

or

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="xyz=negate"]');
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    elems[i].className = elems[i].className + " active";
}
```

Comment: No person posted a CSS only solution which is why I posted it.

Comment: Is this better than getElementBytagname and filter the array and apply the class?